# React production mess up between css files for desktop and mobiles

Tags: css, reactjs, apache, gzip, production-environment

I'm developping a website with react. To differentiate mobiles users and desktop users I'm using a little script which I integrate on all my pages:

```
if (/Android|iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent)) require("link/to/mobile/stylesheet");
else require("link/to/desktop/stylesheet");
```

The problem is that during the developpement build it works well but when I send the production version to my Apache server it sort of mix both of the styles. I'm pretty sure this is because of the gzip compression (which unify all css in one file) but I have absolutely no idea of how to avoid it. Plus, I found nobody with the same issue of mine over the internet. Any idea ?

Here are two pictures, one of how it is supposed to look like, the other which is the production build. This is worse for other parts of the website.[Production (messed up one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE9zm.jpg) [Original One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hP54.jpg)

Comment: Are you using a bundler? What you'll usually see is that a production build get's compiled, whereas a development build is served a lot like the original source. I have a hunch your bundler is configured to spew out 1 css files. popular bundler include [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/).
disregarding that, it might be beneficial to style according to screen size instead of  device used. all your mobile css rules would then simply be wrapped in a media query for sizes are common for mobile.

Comment: I'm not using any bundler, well i think because I didn't install any one. I'm just using the native production build of React and the reason I am not using media queries is because I've always use this script and it always worked fine. But if I can't get it to work I will use media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We moved to [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/192864),

## recap:

create-react-app was used to setup the project
create-react-app is using webpack as its bundler,

When running a local dev server, the css files aren't bundled. However when creating a production build using `npm build --production`. The default configuration will bundle all css into 1 file.

## Solution:

Either make sure the bundled css handles is valid for both mobile and desktop. IE by using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
Or modify the webpack config to create 2 seperate css files.

Quentin is going to try to seperate the css files through webpack. using this [article](https://medium.com/trabe/multiple-css-bundles-with-webpack-75f263095f09) as a starting point.

I wished him the best of luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22931317)

Comment: @LocoGris, Fair enough, added a bit more context and a link to the chat transcript.  Although how much of answer can you really provide if the question boils down to: 'The software i'm using is doing more than I expected'

Comment: I finally used media queries to build my website, the native react scripts for webpack are too complicated to understand and with this solution, I can adapt my site to many viewport sizes.